# Modify keys in Spray JSON

Tags: scala, akka-http, spray-json

Suppose I have a JSON object as follows:

```
{ 
  "CATEGORY": "reference",
  "AUTHOR": "Nigel Rees",
  "TITLE": "Sayings of the Century",
  "PRICE": 8.95
}
```

This flows in the system as a `JsObject`. Using Spray, how would I lowercase these fields?

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
import spray.json._

val str =
    """{"CATEGORY": "reference",
        "AUTHOR":  "Nigel Rees",
        "TITLE": "Sayings of the Century",
        "PRICE": 8.95}"""

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit =
    println(JsObject(str.parseJson.asJsObject.fields.map(el => el._1.asInstanceOf[String].toLowerCase -> el._2 )))
```

gives:

```
{"author":"Nigel Rees","category":"reference","price":8.95,"title":"Sayings of the Century"}
```

With the following dependence in sbt:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.1.8"
```